# Using an ets table for a gen_server state

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I am writing a gen_server which I want to hold an ets table as a state, then ets table was created somewhere else. How should I add this to the state of the gen_server?

I want to use the ets table rather than create a new dictionary for it because I want to save memory.

Also, How does one iterate through a ets table? I want to iterate or read each value in the table and check the value, then I want to do one of two options depending on the value.

Would it be easier just to turn the ets table into a list and traverse the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Read the ETS man page: `erl -man ets`
- An ETS table is identified either by its name (in the case of the `named_table` option) or by its table id. Pass that information to the gen_server and keep it in the state:

  ```
  -record(state, { ..., tbl = none }).


  init([TableID]) ->
      ...,
      {ok, #state { tbl = TableID }}.
  ```

ETS will perhaps not save that much memory. There is a new flag coming up for a later Erlang/OTP release where ETS tables can be `compressed` so their contents are compressed before storage and uncompressed upon reads (there is a computational overhead to this).

To iterate through an ETS table you have several options. `ets:first/1 ets:next/2` is one such interface. `ets:foldl/3 ets:foldr/3` another. `ets:match/3` gives you a continuation (a cursor) to walk with. `ets:select` is even more general than match.

Would it be easier to turn it into a list? This depends. The power of an ETS table is that they have an option `{keypos, N}` defining a key on which elements are stored. `ets:lookup(?TAB, Key)` is extremely fast so you have fast lookups on keys. It is not so with lists. But on the other hand, if you always traverse all of the list it may be a simpler solution (as long as you don't pass the large list between processes).

Turning the whole table into a list and traversing it should perhaps be avoided. You will generate the list in memory and then traverse it which is expensive. It is way better to traverse it a bit at a time so the amount of live memory is low.

Comment: Thanks.A few issues I want to do correctly. We create an ets table for the torrent representation before creating the binary bitfield. I would like to read the ets table and create a queue from the chunks that are needed. This queue will be accessed by the peer handler to avoid duplicate requests. once the chunk is received correctly the item is removed from the queue and the bitfield or torrent state is updated. I want to keep track of the torrent state for the GUI to display a progress bar etc. I am wondering if I should create a dictionary from the ets table or just edit the table directly?

Comment: etorrent uses a two-stage process. Each peer individually reads the ETS table and decides and what it wants. But the table is `protected` so all actual assignment happens in a second stage: The governing chunk manager is called and it serializes access to the table so no two processes grab the same chunk by accident. It yields effective parallelism while still providing progress and safety.

Comment: Ok, well we are going to create a queue from the needed chunks. Do the chunks not reside on disk, if they arent in memory e.g. ets table. I guess a chunk manager can keep track of what is being grabbed and block duplicate grabs, but by grab or the accessing of data,is that done until the entire binary is sent?

Comment: Since you ask: I send 16K chunk binary data straight to the right location on disk and never keep them around in memory. Thus, we get to exercise the kernels disk caching layer as soon as possible (it does a better job than us) and we keep the memory down in the client. What is stored in the ETS table is what we have en disk and what not. Upon *piece* completion, we read the whole piece back from disk, SHA1 it, and validate/invalidate it. If we get a piece fast, the disk cache holds all of it anyway, so the price is not high